Восстановить игру в слова

два друга играют в слова. на вход в программу подается количество слов,  которое сказал каждый из них. затем по порядку подаются слова (сначала по порядку те, которые сказал первый, затем те, которые сказал второй). Напишите программу на c#, которая восстановит и выведет в консоль порядок, в котором эти слова были сказаны в игре (слово первого, слово второго, опять слово первого и т д). Слова могут быть даны не в том порядке, в котором они сказаны в игре.

Подскажите как решать или в какую сторону думать. (пытался объединять по парам и складывать, пытался делать полный перебор вариантов(не придумал алгоритм)

Если бы вам без программирования дали задачу эту, как бы вы стали решать на бумажке? Вот и алгоритм так же будет выглядеть.

Если бы был просто набор слов
Граф. Вершины - буквы. Рёбра (ориентированные) - слова. Найти эйлеров путь.
Когда слова разделены по игрокам
Двудольный граф. Вершины каждой из долей - буквы. Слово первого является ребром из первой доли во вторую, второго - в обратную сторону. Найти эйлеров путь, начинающийся в первой доли.

Обратная трассировка с перебором при поиске тоже подойдёт?

@aepot, не понимаю. Задача симметрична и кажется, что неважно, с какого конца начинать. И вообще, построение пути эйлера начинается с вершины, с нечётной степенью, а дальше наматываем.

Там вариантов полного перебора смешное количество. Даже слово "граф" вспоминать не надо. Просто если угадывать не вспоминая ограничений, а с ограничениями и того меньше. Обычный перебор с обратной трассировкой пути и пометкой ранее использованного выбора.
